# In dart web projects, shouldn't type and reference warnings be errors?

Tags: dart

In dart, when developing a web application, if I invoke a method with a wrong number of arguments, the editor shows a warning message, the javascript compilation however runs successfully, and an error is only raised runtime. This is also the case for example if I refer and unexistent variable, or I pass a method argument of the wrong type.

I ask, if the editor already know that things won't work, why is the compilation successful? Why do we have types if they are not checked at compile time? I guess this behaviour has a reason, but I couldn't find it explained anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no compilation stage. What you see is warning based on type.  For example:

This code will have warning:

```dart
void main() {
  var foo = "";
  foo.baz(); 
}
```

but this one won't:

```dart
void main() {
  var foo;
  foo.baz(); 
}
```

because code analyzer cant deduct the type of `foo`

Comment: hmm I guess here's the explanation I was looking for https://www.dartlang.org/articles/why-dart-types/

Answer (score 3):

In Dart, many programming errors are warnings.
This is for two reasons.

The primary reason is that it allows you to run your program while you are developing it. If some of your code isn't complete yet, or it's only half refactored and still uses the old variable names, you can still test the other half. If you weren't allowed to run the program before it was perfect, that would not be possible.

The other reason is that warnings represent only static type checking, which doesn't know everything about your program, It might be that your program will work, it's just impossible for the analyser to determine.

Example:

```dart
class C {
  int foo(int x) => x;
}
class D implements C {
  num foo(num x, [num defaultValue]) => x == null ? defaultValue : x;
}
void bar(C c) => print(c.foo(4.1, 42));  // Static warning: wrong argument count, bad type.
main() { bar(new D()); }  // Program runs fine.
```

If your program works, it shouldn't be stopped by a pedantic analyser that only knows half the truth. You should still look at the warnings, and consider whether there is something to worry about, but it is perfectly fine to decide that you actually know better than the compiler.

Comment: hmm, this is a strange approach for Java developers :) Also, in your example, the method bar is just wrong. The program runs fine indeed, but the declaration of the method 'bar' is wrong by OO semantics.